# wrong pageY calculation when parent div has position:relative

Tags: javascript, css, events, position

`e.pageY`doesn't give proper result when parent div has `position:relative` css property

**Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mDBzy**

At the same time result seems to fine without `position:relative` of the parent div:

```
#mydiv{
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px; 
  /* position: relative; */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I imagined... e.pageY is working properly.

The offsetTop value when you have no "position:" rule is 158. As soon as you add "position:relative;" your offsetTop will be 0. Why? I **assume** that when there was no position:relative it was getting the offset relative to the body. With position:relative, it was getting the offset relative to "mydiv".

Solution for this particular example: instead of "vControl.offsetTop", use the fixed number "158".

Perhaps someone with more experience will explain better and offer the best solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort. I think `offsetParent` can give a better solution.

Comment: No problem, I'm here to help!